# JavaFX Using Custom Listview to using CheckBox with setCellFactory

Tags: javafx

When I read JavaFX book, they use TodoItem class (1)

```
final class TodoItem {
    final String name;
    final BooleanProperty isDone = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public TodoItem(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + (isDone.get() ? " DONE" : "");
    }
}
```

and ObservableList (2)

```
ObservableList<TodoItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList((TodoItem item)
    -> { return new Observable[] { item.isDone }; });
```

and CellFactory (3)

```
list.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView( item -> item.isDone ));
```

to show the program like:

[image: screenshot]

When I check a CheckBox, text next to CheckBox will be added "DONE".
And when I uncheck a CheckBox, "DONE" will disappear.
***Main content is below***
I want to write another version of (3) like

```
list.setCellFactory((ListView<TodoItem> param) -> {
    return new ListCell<> () {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(TodoItem item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (!(empty || item == null)) {
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                item.isDone.bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());
                
                setGraphic(checkBox);
                setText(item.name);
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

I create a CheckBox, I bind isDone Property to CheckBox.
And I think, isDone is observable, and isDone is bound with CheckBox,
when I check a CheckBox, It should make isDone to true, and update the text with "DONE".
Please help me find my mistake, and help me solve my problem, thank so much.

Comment: I understand what the text book example is doing.  But I can’t understand what you are trying to change it to.  How does what you wish to create differ from the text book example? Could you provide a description of the new functionality or a mock up of an image that helps explain it?  You can edit the question with updates if you wish.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: I have an answer below. I want to write a new cell like the cell in the book without using CheckBoxListCell. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to use the CheckBoxListCell and you want to write your own cell factory. The main change you need to do in your logic is to not create a new CheckBox in the updateItem call. You need to set one CheckBox per each cell. So for that you need to declare a CheckBox on class level.

Below is one way to implement the code to get the required functionality.

```
listView.setCellFactory((ListView<TodoItem> param) -> new ListCell<TodoItem>() {
    private CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    private TodoItem itemBkp;

    @Override
    public void updateItem(TodoItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (itemBkp != null) {
            itemBkp.isDoneProperty().unbindBidirectional(checkBox.selectedProperty());
        }
        if (!(empty || item == null)) {
            item.isDoneProperty().bindBidirectional(checkBox.selectedProperty());
            setGraphic(checkBox);
            setText(item.toString());
            itemBkp = item;
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
            itemBkp = null;
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comment, there is a little bug in the above provided code. So I reworked on the implementation. The below code should address the issue mentioned in the comment. In this approach, we dont need any item backup as we are not binding any properties.

```
listView.setCellFactory((ListView<TodoItem> param) -> new ListCell<TodoItem>() {
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    public void updateItem(TodoItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!(empty || item == null)) {
            getCheckBox().setSelected(item.isDoneProperty().getValue());
            setGraphic(getCheckBox());
            setText(item.toString());
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        }
    }
    private CheckBox getCheckBox(){
        if(checkBox==null){
            checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs,old,val)->{
                if(getItem()!=null){
                    getItem().isDoneProperty().setValue(val);
                }
            });
        }
        return checkBox;
    }
});
```

[image]

Below is the complete code of the demo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewCheckBoxDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<TodoItem> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setCellFactory((ListView<TodoItem> param) -> new ListCell<TodoItem>() {
            private CheckBox checkBox;

            @Override
            public void updateItem(TodoItem item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!(empty || item == null)) {
                    getCheckBox().setSelected(item.isDoneProperty().getValue());
                    setGraphic(getCheckBox());
                    setText(item.toString());
                } else {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                }
            }

            private CheckBox getCheckBox() {
                if (checkBox == null) {
                    checkBox = new CheckBox();
                    checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
                        if (getItem() != null) {
                            getItem().isDoneProperty().setValue(val);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return checkBox;
            }
        });

        ObservableList<TodoItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> new Observable[]{item.isDone});
        items.addAll(new TodoItem("Sign a Contract"), new TodoItem("Fail Deadline"), new TodoItem("Blame Yourself"), new TodoItem("Suffer"));
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
            items.add(new TodoItem("Testing " + i));
        }
        listView.setItems(items);

        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("Mark 4th item as done (external updating)");
        cb.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
            listView.getItems().get(3).isDoneProperty().setValue(val);
        });
        VBox root = new VBox(cb, listView);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("ListView CheckBox Demo");
        stage.show();
    }

    final class TodoItem {
        private final String name;
        private final BooleanProperty isDone = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        public TodoItem(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + (isDone.get() ? " DONE" : "");
        }

        public BooleanProperty isDoneProperty() {
            return isDone;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the itemBkp variable mean? When I delete itemBkp variable, program still works properly.

Comment: That variable is to unbind the properties of the previous item that is associated with this list cell. I agree that in this case it has no impact. But once you have enough rows to have a vertical scroll bar, the cell are reused for the items that are visible. In such cases you need to ensure that you first unbind the previously associated item. To check its impact., add some 20 to 30 items - scroll to last item - select the last checkbox - now  scroll to top.. you will notice that some other items are also selected.

Comment: I tried like you say, 1 case with itemBkp and 1 case without itemBkp, both cases lead to 1 result: When I select the checkbox, scroll up and down, and another checkbox are selected. How to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I updated the answer with the fix.